# How to solve this geometric/arithmetic sequence problem without guessing and checking?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Which represents the sum of $6+15+26+39$ ?
>
> 1. $\sum\limits_{n=4}^7 (2n-2)$
> 2. $\sum\limits_{n=4}^7 (n^2-10)$
> 3. $\sum\limits_{n=2}^5 (n^2+n)$
> 4. $\sum\limits_{n=2}^5 \mathopen{\Big(}\dfrac{3n^2}{2}\mathclose{\Big)}$

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1es18.png))

I can employ guess and check and arrive at the answer of choice 2 (by just plugging in each variable, but is there any way to directly solve for the equation (ie, not given the answer choices)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "directly solve for the equation" (at any rate, you mean *expression*, not equation; note the lack of equals signs), because you can find infinitely many expressions that will have the same value as
$$6+15+26+39=86.$$
You can even find infinitely many polynomials $f$ and integers $a$ such that
$$f(a)=6,\quad f(a+1)=15,\quad f(a+2)=26,\quad f(a+3)=39$$
so that the expression
$$\sum_{n=a}^{a+3}f(n)$$
represents the same summation. There is no "canonical" or "natural" way of taking a sum of integers and making an expression that "does the same thing". In short: the only way of solving the question you are considering is to check the answer choices given.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible answer, using Mathematica's built in function:

```
FindSequenceFunction[{6, 15, 26, 39}]
```

gives the answer

```
-1 + 6 #1 + #1^2 &
```

which means that these are consecutive elements of the polynomial

```
x^2 + 6 x -1
```

While this is not one of the choices in your list, it is a structured way of generating these four numbers.